# $L^p$ space of vector fields is complete

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry

Let $(M,g,\mu)$ be a weighted Riemannian manifold.

I want to show that the $\vec{L}^p$ space of measurable vector fields on $M$ is complete.
I tried using the fact completeness is equivalent to convergence of absolutely convergent series.

If $(X_n)$ is a sequence of vector fields with $|X_n| \in L^p$ s.t. $\sum_{n\in \mathbb N} \|X_n\|_p < \infty$, then by the completeness of ordinary $L^p$ the sequence $(|X_n|)$ must converge in $L^p$ to some $f$.

But this doesn't seem to tell me all that much since I don't a vector field $X_\infty$ with $|X_\infty| = f$ this way.

How can the statement be proven?

Comment: This may not be very satisfactoy, but in the measurable category, every vector bundle is trivial. Thus the problem reduces to $L^p(M;\mathbb{R}^n)$, which can be treated componentwise. I hope someone else can give you a nicer (or at least more detailed) answer.

Comment: @MaoWao Yeah, unfortunately I can't follow that at all with my current level of understanding ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a start.

Let $(U_n,\mathbf{X}_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be an atlas, and let $(\varphi_n:M\to\mathbb{R})_n$ be a smooth partition of unity subordinate to $(U_n)_n$. Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be a Cauchy sequence of $L^p$ vector fields on $M$. Then for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ the sequence $\varphi_nX_1,\varphi_nX_2,\ldots$ is a Cauchy sequence of $L^p$ vector fields compactly supported in $U_n$. As $TM|_{U_n}$ is trivial, the last sequence can be thought of as a Cauchy sequence of $L^p$ functions $U_n\to\mathbb{R}^k$ (where $k=\dim M$).

The above argument shows local convergence. What you have left to do is is patch all the local limits up to a global limit of the original sequence.